# Lazy load в элементе Tree фреймворка ExtJs 4.1.1

Tags: javascript, python, django, extjs

Я изучаю ExtJs в связке с Django. Недавно реализовал построение элемента tree из файла json, содержащего данные из базы данных sqlite3.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код данной реализации поместил на github: https://github.com/ArturV19/for_stack_overflow_extjs_lazy_load

Теперь у меня задача реализовать "ленивую" загрузку, то есть что бы сначала с сервера загружался только список жанров, а уже при нажатии на определённый жанр подгружались авторы, пишущие в данном жанре.

Код модели книги в models.py:

```
class BookModel(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
genre = models.CharField(max_length=190)

def __str__(self):
    return self.author + ': ' + self.title + ' (' + self.genre + ')'
```

Код html-страницы templates/Index_LazyDownload.html:

```html
{% load staticfiles %}

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Combobox</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'extjs-4.1.1/resources/css/ext-all-debug.css' %}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'extjs-4.1.1/ext-all-debug.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'lazyload_tree.js' %}"></script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Код приложения ExtJs:

```js
Ext.onReady(function () {

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        proxy:{
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '../lazy_download_get_genres/'
        }
    });

    var tree1 = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        title: 'Жанры',
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        store: store,
        rootVisible: false,
    });

    var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        title: 'Форма ввода',
        width: 250,
        autoHeight: true,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        defaults: {
            labelWidth: 100
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            id: 'searchField1',
            fieldLabel: 'Поиск по названию:',
            name: 'searchField',
        },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text : 'Начать поиск',
                margin:'15 0 0 25',
                listeners: {
                    click: function() {
                        panel.setLoading('Loading...')
                        store.load(
                            {
                                type: 'ajax',
                                url: '../get_json_search_books/'+Ext.getCmp('searchField1').getValue()
                                ,
                                callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                                    // the operation object
                                    // contains all of the details of the load operation
                                    panel.setLoading(false)
                                }});
                    }
                }
            }
            ],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });

    var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'Книжная полка с попыткой "ленивой" загрузки:',
        width: 1072,
        padding:10,
        height: 400,
        autoload: true,
        layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
        items: [tree1, formPanel],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

**Далее идут ещё фрагменты кода python**

TreeApp/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from TreeApp import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.tree_index),
path('get_json_for_tree/', views.get_json_for_tree),
path('get_json_search_books/<str:text>', views.get_json_search_books),
path('lazy_load/', views.lazy_download_page),
path('lazy_download_get_genres/', views.lazy_download_get_genres),
]
```

TreeApp/view.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from TreeApp.methods_for_lazy_load import json_of_genres_lazy_load
from TreeApp.work_with_database import get_string_json_genres_and_authors, 
get_string_json_genres_and_authors_search


# Возвращает html-страницу
def tree_index(request):
    return render(request, "Index.html")


# Возвращает JSON-объект для генерации дерева
def get_json_for_tree(request):
    return HttpResponse(get_string_json_genres_and_authors())


# Возвращает JSON-объект для генерации дерева
# из книг, соответствующих условию
def get_json_search_books(request, text):
    return HttpResponse(get_string_json_genres_and_authors_search(text))

############################################################################
# Далее идут методы для 'ленивой' загрузки
############################################################################


def lazy_download_page(request):
    return render(request, "Index_LazyDownload.html")


def lazy_download_get_genres(request):
    return HttpResponse(json_of_genres_lazy_load())
```

work_with_database.py:

```
from TreeApp.models import BookModel


# Получение авторов, пишущих в данном жанре
def get_authors_in_this_genre(genre):
    book_list_in_genre = BookModel.objects.filter(genre=genre)

    output = set()

    for book in book_list_in_genre:
        dict_author = {book.author}
        output.update(dict_author)

    return output


# Набор жанров
def get_set_of_unique_genres():

    book_list = BookModel.objects.all()

    output = set()

    for book in book_list:
        dict_genres = {book.genre}
        output.update(dict_genres)

    return output


def get_string_books_of_author_in_this_genre(genre, author):
    target_books = BookModel.objects.filter(author=author, genre=genre)

    string_books = '['
    for book in target_books:
        string_books += '{"text" : "' + book.title + '" , ' + '"leaf" : "true"},'

    # Удаления запятой в конце
    string_books = string_books[:-1] + '],'

    return string_books


def get_string_books_of_author_in_this_genre_search(genre, author, books):
    target_books = books.filter(author=author, genre=genre)

    string_books = '['
    for book in target_books:
        string_books += '{"text" : "' + book.title + '" , ' + '"leaf" : "true"},'

    # Удаления запятой в конце
    string_books = string_books[:-1] + '],'

    return string_books


# Получение json-строки для двухуровнего дерева,
# где сначала идёт список жанров
def get_string_json_genres_and_authors():

    genres_list = get_set_of_unique_genres()

    # Итоговая строка
    string_request = '['

    for genre in genres_list:

        # Строка, относящаяся к отдельному жанру
        string_genre = '{"text" : "' + genre + '", "children" : '

        list_authors_in_genre = get_authors_in_this_genre(genre)

        # Строка, относящаяся к отдельному автору в жанре
        string_authors = '['

        for author in list_authors_in_genre:
            string_authors += '{"text" : "'+author+'" , "children" : '
            string_authors += get_string_books_of_author_in_this_genre(genre, author)+' "leaf" : "false"},'

        string_authors = string_authors[:-1]

        string_genre += string_authors
        string_genre += '], "leaf" : "false"},'

        string_request += string_genre

    string_request = string_request[:-1]+']'

    return string_request


def get_string_json_genres_and_authors_search(search_string):

    books = BookModel.objects.filter(title__contains=search_string)

    # Список жанров
    genres_output = set()

    for book in books:
        dict_genres = {book.genre}
        genres_output.update(dict_genres)

    # Итоговая строка JSON
    string_request = '['

    for genre in genres_output:

        # Строка, относящаяся к отдельному жанру
        string_genre = '{"text" : "' + genre + '", "children" : '

        book_list_in_genre = books.filter(genre=genre)

        # Список авторов
        output_authors = set()

        for book in book_list_in_genre:
            dict_author = {book.author}
            output_authors.update(dict_author)

        # Строка, относящаяся к отдельному автору в жанре
        string_authors = '['

        for author in output_authors:
            string_authors += '{"text" : "'+author+'" , "children" : '
            string_authors += get_string_books_of_author_in_this_genre_search(genre, author, books)+' "leaf" : "false"},'

        string_authors = string_authors[:-1]

        string_genre += string_authors
        string_genre += '], "leaf" : "false"},'

        string_request += string_genre

    string_request = string_request[:-1]+']'

    return string_request
```

methods_for_lazy_load.py:

```
from TreeApp.work_with_database import get_set_of_unique_genres


def json_of_genres_lazy_load():
    genres_list = get_set_of_unique_genres()

    # Итоговая строка
    string_request = '['

    for genre in genres_list:

        # Строка, относящаяся к отдельному жанру
        string_genre = '{"text" : "' + genre + '"'

        string_genre += ', "leaf" : "false"},'

        string_request += string_genre

    string_request = string_request[:-1]+']'

    return string_request
```

Вывод в данный момент выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь, из официальной документации нужной информации получить не смог.

**Важно, нужна реализация именно в версии ExtJs 4.1.1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на данный вопрос был найден. Код решения выложен на GitHub по адресу: https://github.com/ArturV19/for_stack_overflow_extjs_lazy_load. Теперь, постараюсь подробно объяснить, как я организовал "ленивую" загрузку.

Во-первых, код самого приложения ExtJs (https://github.com/ArturV19/for_stack_overflow_extjs_lazy_load/blob/master/static/lazyload_tree.js) выглядит так:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    let store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        proxy:{
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '../lazy_download_get_data/'
        }
    });

    let tree1 = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        title: 'Жанры',
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        store: store,
        rootVisible: false,
        listeners: {
            //Перед открытием нажатого узла дерева:
            beforeitemexpand: function (node) {

                //console.log('expand, ' + node.getDepth() + ' ');
                //console.log('expand, ' + node.getDepth() + ' ' + node.parentNode.data.text);

                //Устанавливаем значения дополнительных параметров:
                store.getProxy().setExtraParam("node" , node.data.text);
                store.getProxy().setExtraParam("level", node.getDepth());
                store.getProxy().setExtraParam("parent_text", node.parentNode.data.text);
            }
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'Книжная полка с "ленивой" загрузкой',
        width: 1072,
        padding:10,
        height: 400,
        autoload: false,
        layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
        items: [tree1],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

Вот так выглядит страница при загрузке:
[image: Начальный вид страницы]

Тут нужно остановиться на элементе tree.Panel подробнее. Дело в том, что при нажатии на любой элемент дерева будет происходить загрузка из хранилища store. Store, в свою очередь, выполняет запрос на сервер (в данном случае - **ajax-запрос** по адресу '../lazy_download_get_data/') и передаёт полученные с сервера данные "дереву". Поэтому, если не менять никаких параметров, то при нажатии на какой-либо жанр снова будет открываться список жанров, как было в моём вопросе до этого:
[image: Неудачная реализация]

Теперь же, с каждым нажатием на элемент дерева, на сервер передаются такие данные как:

1. Текст записи - node.data.text (например, при нажатии на жанр "Юмор", передаётся "Юмор")
2. Глубина узла в дереве (при нажатии на какой-либо жанр передаётся 1, а при нажатии на писателя 2)
3. Текст записи родительского элемента (например, при нажатии узла "Стивен Кинг" в жанре "Ужасы", передастся именно "Ужасы"; название интересующего жанра нужно знать, чтобы не загружать книги из других жанров):
   [image: Разные жанры Стивена Кинга]

Кстати, следует отметить, что для формирования дерева tree JSON объект, получаемый с сервера, должен быть валидным, а передаваемые внутри JSON объекты должны содержать необходимые поля, например "text", "leaf" и другие. Более подробно советую почитать тут: https://metanit.com/web/extjs/7.6.php. Валидность кода я проверял с помощью сервиса https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

Во-вторых, рассмотрим более подробно python-код, отвечающий за формирование текста, который станет JSON-объектом (https://github.com/ArturV19/for_stack_overflow_extjs_lazy_load/blob/master/TreeApp/methods_for_lazy_load.py):

```
from TreeApp.work_with_database import get_set_of_unique_genres, get_authors_in_this_genre, \
    get_string_books_of_author_in_this_genre


# Получение JSON-файла с данными для формирования дерева
#
# node - текст записи, которая должна "раскрыться" при нажатии
# node==root - родительский элемент дерева, в который при открытии страницы загружается список жанров
#
# level - "глубина", на которой находится элемент дерева, который нужно раскрыть
#
# parent_text - текст, определяющий "родителя". В данном случае parent_text нужен, чтобы узнать, в котором именно
# жанре искать книги данного автора
def json_of_data_lazy_load(node, level, parent_text):
    string_request = None

    # Если только открываем страницу, формируем строку для JSON-файла со списком жанров
    if str(node) == 'root':

        # Список всех жанров
        genres_list = get_set_of_unique_genres()

        # Итоговая строка
        string_request = '['

        for genre in genres_list:
            # Текст, относящийся к отдельному жанру
            string_genre = '{"text" : "' + genre + '"'

            string_genre += ',"leaf" : "false"},'

            string_request += string_genre

        # Удаления запятой в конце и добавление ']'
        string_request = string_request[:-1] + ']'

    # Если нажимаем на жанр, формируем JSON-строку с авторами, которые пишут в данном жанре
    elif str(level) == '1':

        # Список всех авторов, у которых есть хотя бы одна книга в данном жанре
        authors_list = get_authors_in_this_genre(str(node))

        # Итоговая строка
        string_request = '['

        for author in authors_list:
            # Строка, относящаяся к отдельному автору
            string_author = '{"text" : "' + author + '"'

            string_author += ', "leaf" : "false"},'

            string_request += string_author

        string_request = string_request[:-1] + ']'

    # Если нажимаем на имя автора, формируем JSON-строку с книгами, которые автор написал в данном жанре
    elif str(level) == '2':
        print('level  2')

        string_request = get_string_books_of_author_in_this_genre(str(parent_text), str(node))

        string_request = string_request[:-1]

    print(string_request)
    return string_request
```

При загрузке страницы формируется строка:

```
[{"text" : "Научная фантастика","leaf" : "false"},{"text" : "Ужасы","leaf" : "false"},{"text" : "Антиутопия","leaf" : "false"},{"text" : "Учебная литература","leaf" : "false"},{"text" : "Юмор","leaf" : "false"},{"text" : "Фантастика","leaf" : "false"},{"text" : "Тёмное фэнтези","leaf" : "false"}]
```

При нажатии на на жанр, например "Научная фантастика", будут переданы соответствующие параметры, и сформирован ответ:

```
[{"text" : "Рэй Брэ'дбери", "leaf" : "false"},{"text" : "Питер Уоттс", "leaf" : "false"}]
```

А при нажатии на автора, например, "Рэй Брэ'дбери", будет ответ:

```
[{"text" : "Марсианские хроники" , "leaf" : "true"},{"text" : "И грянул гром" , "leaf" : "true"}]
```

Думаю, для понимания кода этой информации будет достаточно. Кстати, так как пример учебный, то параметры для входа в admin-панель соответствующие: Username: admin, Password: pass. Надеюсь, информация будет полезна для людей, которые, как и я, изучают ExtJs.